# Placeholder is not working with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

***HTML***

*With ng-model* - Not working

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Event.Sponsor.Amount" name="donationAmount" placeholder="{{PlaceHolderOther}}" required />
```

*Without ng-model* - Working

```
 <input type="text" name="donationAmount" placeholder="{{PlaceHolderOther}}" required />
```

***JS***

```
 $scope.PlaceHolderOther = "$50.00";
```

Could you tell me why `placeholder` is not working with `ng-model` ? It's working fine without `ng-model`.Thanks in advance.

**Out put** (When it runs)

```
<input type="text" name="donationAmount" placeholder="$50.00" ng-model="Event.Sponsor.Amount" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required">
```

It shows the `placeholder` value properly.But not display it to the user.Why ?

**UPDATE :** I have found out the issue.That is texbox has been initialized automatically.When we remove that value then it shows the placeholder value.So how to avoid this by default ?

Comment: Try  `$scope.Event = {PlaceHolderOther : '$50.00'}`;

Answer (score -1):

Try `data-ng-model`, refer to http://jsfiddle.net/pranav93/ww3k4hxp/6/ .
Something like,

```
<input id="ship-address-line-3" name="ship_address_line3" placeholder="{{shippingFormOrderItemAction.ship_address_line3}}" data-ng-model="retryAutoDetails.ship_address_line3" type="text">
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you defined

```
$scope.Event = {};
```

Try above with.

Yes: updated answer according.. (typo mistake corrected)

Comment: It should be `$scope.Event`

Comment: The thing is, it is working fine with the `type=number`.But not working with the `text`. It's really strange.

Comment: I dont see relation with text and number, but thought $scope.Event = {}; is the issue.

Comment: Then Can I use like this `$scope.PlaceHolderOther = "$50.00";` ? I have updated my answer too.But still not working ? Why ?

Comment: <input type="text"  name="donationAmount" placeholder="{{PlaceHolderOther}}" ng-model="Event.Sponsor.Amount"  required /> can you change the order of attribute and see if it works.

Comment: Still not working :( I have updated my out put string on the above question.It shows the `placeholder` value properly.But not display it to the user.Why ?

Comment: I have found out the issue.Your fiddle also having that issue.That is texbox     has been initialized automatically.When we remove that value then it shows the placeholder value.So how to avoid this by default ?